# Which JSF version(impl) support UI custom component annotations replacing XML taglib?

Tags: jsf, annotations, mojarra

For a custom JSF component Foo, need to add the following taglib.xml. Which JSF impl (mojarra) version support annotations instead of XML?

```
taglib.xml

<facelet-taglib ...>        

      <namespace>http://xmlns.example.com/</namespace>

    <tag>
        <description>foo</description>
        <tag-name>foo</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>com.example.component.HtmlFoo</component-type>
            <renderer-type>com.example.component.Foo</renderer-type>
        </component>                         
    </tag>      
</facelet-taglib>
```

### UPDATED

```
@FacesComponent(createTag=true, namespace="http://xmlns.example.com/", tagName="foo")
public class HtmlFoo extends UIComponent {

    public HtmlFoo() {
        setRendererType("com.example.component.Foo");
    }

    public String getFamily() {
        return "com.example.component.data";
    }

    // ...
}


public class HtmlFooTag extends UIComponentELTag {
  
  @Override
  public String getComponentType() {
    return "com.example.component.HtmlFoo";
  }

  @Override
  public String getRendererType() {
    return "com.example.component.Foo";
  }

  // ...
}


@FacesRenderer(
        componentFamily="com.example.component.data",
        rendererType="com.example.component.Foo")
public class HtmlFooRenderer extends Renderer {

   //...
}
```

use the tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:g="http://xmlns.example.com/">
     // ...
     <g:foo .../>
</html>
```

Error:

```
<g:foo> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.example.com/, but no tag was defined for name: foo
```

There is no annotation for HtmlFooTag. How it is connected to the component HtmlFoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supported since JSF 2.2, regardless of the implementation (any implementation must adhere the spec nonetheless). Since JSF 2.2, the in JSF 2.0 introduced [`@FacesComponent`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/component/facescomponent) annotation got a [`createTag`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/component/facescomponent#createTag--) attribute which you can set to `true` to skip the XML boilerplate, along with optional `namespace` and `tagName` attributes. You can set the default renderer in the component's constructor.

In other words:

```java
@FacesComponent(createTag=true, namespace="http://xmlns.example.com/", tagName="foo")
public class HtmlFoo extends UIComponent {

    public HtmlFoo() {
        setRendererType("com.example.component.Foo");
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: After replacing xml with the annotation, got error:  <g:foo> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.example.com/, but no tag was defined for name: foo.

Comment: That can happen when you aren't actually using JSF 2.2 or newer. If you are then I'd as first thing try to remove the spurious trailing slash from the namespace URI.

Comment: As per the updated question, the `UIComponentELTag` is for JSP not for Facelets. JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0. You really aren't using JSP are you? It's ignored by Facelets nonetheless, so you can safely remove the unused class.

Comment: Removed HtmlFooTag. JSF version 2.2.20: jsf-api-2.2.20.jar,
jsf-impl-2.2.20.jar. Changed namespace to http://xmlns.example.com/html. But still got the same error: no tag defined for name: foo. Thanks.

Comment: After deleting taglib.xml, it works. But it did not work after proguard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872493/jsf-could-not-find-facescomponent-after-proguard